# Set subtraction while keeping duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the set *subtraction* of two string arrays while **considering duplicates**.

Ex:

```
var a = new string[] {"1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4"};
var b = new string[] {"2", "3"};
```

> (a - b) => expected output => string[] {"1", "2", "4", "4"}

I already tried `Enumerable.Except()` which returns the *unique* values after subtract: `{ "1", "4" }` which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this without a custom implementation?

Comment: Do you want to preserve order? Can `a` be like `4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2`, and what would then the output be?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Nope. No need to worry about order.

Comment: So for the input given by me, the output `4, 4, 1, 2` would be fine?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yup that's fine.

Comment: I am not concerned with **output** order. I am asking if we can rely on the **inputs** being ordered (since it makes the problem easier).

Comment: @mjwills: Yes you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var a = new string[] { "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4" }.ToList();
var b = new string[] { "2", "3" };

foreach (var element in b)
{
    a.Remove(element);
}
```

Has been tested.

Comment: Nice, compact, but can be *slow* - `O(N * M)` time complexity. Grouping has `O(N + M)` one; +1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will go ahead with this due to simplicity and my lists are small having less than 10 items.

Comment: Using `BinarySearch` and `RemoveAt` may be worth considering. Particularly useful since you can specify `startIndex` to avoid searching the whole `List`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `GroupBy`, and work with *groups* e.g.

```
var a = new string[] {"1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4"};
var b = new string[] {"2", "3"};

...

var subtract = b
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());

var result = a
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .Select(chunk => new {
     value = chunk.Key,
     count = chunk.Count() - (subtract.TryGetValue(chunk.Key, out var v) ? v : 0)  
   })
  .Where(item => item.count > 0)
  .SelectMany(item => Enumerable.Repeat(item.value, item.count));

// Let's have a look at the result
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 2, 4, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will go ahead with Peter's answer due to simplicity.

Comment: @Wijitha: It's totally up to you. My solution has a better perfomance on large arrays: `O(N + M)` time complexity vs `O(N * M)`, Peter's answer is much simpler. If lists have `10` items or less, time complexity doesn't play any role

Answer (score 3):

By leveraging the undersung [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8) (which allows you to create dictionary-like structure with multi-values per key) you can do this quite efficiently. Here, because key lookups on non-existent keys in an `ILookup` return empty `IGrouping` (rather than `null` or an error), you can avoid a whole bunch of null-checks/`TryGet...`-boilerplate. Because `Enumerable.Take` with a negative value is equivalent to `Enumerable.Take(0)`, we don't have to check our arithmetic either.

```
var aLookup = a.ToLookup(x => x);
var bLookup = b.ToLookup(x => x);
var filtered = aLookup
    .SelectMany(aItem => aItem.Take(aItem.Count() - bLookup[aItem.Key].Count()));
```

Comment: Splendid! Very good example when we don't have to check with `TryGetValue` or `count > 0`; +1